# Setting default value based on database in DJango

Tags: django, django-forms

Good evening,

I am new to Django and am working on a sort of ticketing app.  My app has three models, Ticket, Status, & Notes.

When displaying the ticket details, I have a form to add a Note.  What I want to do is to add to the form a drop down that is set to the current status value of the ticket.  When creating the form, how do I pass in the current status value to the form and use it as the default value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can set it when calling the form constructor in your view:

```
form = NoteForm(initial={'status': ticket.status})
```

Comment: Awesome.... thanks.  Everything I was digging up on GoogleFu was either too basic that this wasn't covered, or so advanced that I had no idea what I was looking at (it was probably in there somewhere).